# session set in folders php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session

i have this code:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if(mysql_num_rows($result80)>0)
 {
    $row80 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result80);
    $_SESSION["loginmng"] = 1;
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
    $fname = $row80["fname"];
    $lname = $row80["lname"];
    $userid = $row80["id"];
 }
```

and every thing is ok because i tryed to echo the session and its work in the same page (index.php)
now i have this check:

```
if(($_SESSION["loginmng"]!=1)||(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))||(!isset($_SESSION["password"])))
{
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

when i put this into new folder:
**newfolder/index.php**
the check is not working right,when i have logged in , and the session is set....when i am tring to `echo $_SESSION["loginmng"]` and the other sessions,,its values is empty like no session setted and the header is got run ...and go to index...i have put `session_start();` in the first php line too
i tryed too:

```
if($_SESSION["loginmng"]!=1)
{
  header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

and the same thing...like no session set, what may be the problem

Comment: are you 100% sure the session is started? `session_start()` on top?

Comment: Can you put all the code from both files, to get a better view?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem yet, but I do want to save you from a mistake that cost me many hours.  If you ever echo anything, than you cannot redirect with header("Location: ...")

Comment: Is session_start() at the top of the code in the first chunk?

Comment: @MihaiIorga thank you man , for truth i forgot session_start(); i didnt look good for the file , and i thought that session start is included , thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

A PHP session variable is used to store information about, or change settings for a user session. Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.
PHP Session Variables

When you are working with an application, you open it, do some changes and then you close it. This is much like a Session. The computer knows who you are. It knows when you start the application and when you end. But on the internet there is one problem: the web server does not know who you are and what you do because the HTTP address doesn't maintain state.

A PHP session solves this problem by allowing you to store user information on the server for later use (i.e. username, shopping items, etc). However, session information is temporary and will be deleted after the user has left the website. If you need a permanent storage you may want to store the data in a database.

Sessions work by creating a unique id (UID) for each visitor and store variables based on this UID. The UID is either stored in a cookie or is propagated in the URL.
Starting a PHP Session

Before you can store user information in your PHP session, you must first start up the session.

Note: The `session_start()` function must appear BEFORE the `<html>` tag.

Comment: A security measure (not related exactly to your question): If you gonna store the user details as usernames and passwords in session variables, store them not in plain text, but encrypted, or hashed with, let`s say sha1() function, then compare/assign the hash with the hashed value from database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to add `session_start();` on top of the file.

To make session start on each page you need to start the session on each page.

*`session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a `GET` or `POST` request, or passed via a cookie.*